# Trouble with delimiting colon with scanf

Tags: c, scanf

I am having some trouble using `scanf`. The input I want to read will be this format:

```
string:integer:
```

For instance, `ptest/src/test.c:19:blahblahblah`

Would be a valid string. I want to store `p2test/src/test.c` and `19`. However, I've run into some problems, namely, `19` does not get read in.

Here is what I am trying:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        char *str;
        char *i;
        int n = 0;
        scanf("%m[^':'], %m[^':']", &str, &i);

        printf("# inputs read: %d\n", n);
        printf("%s\n", str);
        printf("%s\n", i);
        return 0;


}
```

In the end, I got 1 input read and only `ptest/src/test.c` was printed. Another issue is that the `m` flag I used gets warnings from gcc. I am using C89 and I got the same warning while using `a` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the formatting is wrong, you want to read the colon and there are no commas. Try this:

```c
scanf("%m[^':']:%m[^':']", &str, &i);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh I see. Would you mind explaining how replacing the comma with the colon in the middle works?

Comment: You want to tell `scanf` the format of the input string that you're expecting. The formatting string `"%m[^':']:%m[^':']"` can be understood as: take a string that contains anything except colons (`%m[^':']`) and store it, then take a colon (`:`), then take another string that contains anything except colons (`%m[^':']` again) and store it. If you had kept it as `"%m[^':'], %m[^':']"`, then that means: find a string, then find a comma and a space, then find another string.